# How do I use Facebook API to search for posts with a keyword?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had previously written a program to find Facebook posts containing a specific work, using the html: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=keyword&type=post.  This used to work, but Facebook seems to required authentication now, and I am not sure how to do it. (even reading their developer pages)  I am asking for all public posts, regardless of user, and I an calling from a php program.  Do I need to log myself in from php?  How?  They talk about an app id, and an app secret, and I am not sure which I need and how to use it to authenticate myself.

Comment: Start from facebook php sdk example

Comment: The issue at hand is a fundamental lack of investigative work on your end. Please don't post such low quality questions in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply, not.  If I have read the Facebook documentation and don't think it is specific enough, where should I look next?  I will look at the facebook php examples, as zerkms suggests.  If it still leaves holes in my understanding I will be back.